# How to pass multiple group_by arguments and a dynamic variable argument to a dplyr function

Tags: r, dplyr, quosure

I am trying to pass multiple group_by arguments to a dplyr function as well as a named variable.  In understand that I need to use a quosure for dplyr to understand the variables i am passing to it.  The following code works fine:

```
quantileMaker2 <- function(data, groupCol, calcCol) {
  groupCol <- enquo(groupCol)
  calcCol <- enquo(calcCol)

  data %>%
    group_by(!! groupCol) %>%
      summarise('25%' = currency(quantile(!! calcCol, probs = 0.25), digits = 2L),
            '50%' = currency(quantile(!! calcCol, probs = 0.50), digits = 2L),
            '75%' = currency(quantile(!! calcCol, probs = 0.75), digits = 2L),
            avg = currency(mean(!! calcCol), digits = 2L),
            nAgencies = n_distinct('POSIT ID'), 
            nFTEs = sum(FTEs)
  )
}

quantileMaker2(df, employerClass, TCCperFTE)
```

However when I run the following I have a problem:

```
quantileMaker3 <- function(data,...,calcCol) {
  groupCol <- quos(...)
  calcCol <- quo(calcCol)

  data %>%
    group_by(!!! groupCol) %>%
    summarise('25%' = currency(quantile(!! calcCol, probs = 0.25), digits = 2L),
          '50%' = currency(quantile(!! calcCol, probs = 0.50), digits = 2L),
          '75%' = currency(quantile(!! calcCol, probs = 0.75), digits = 2L),
          avg = currency(mean(!! calcCol), digits = 2L),
          nAgencies = n_distinct('POSIT ID'), 
          nFTEs = sum(FTEs)
)
}
```

Which returns the following error:

```
 Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'symbol'.
```

Sample data:

```
Year    employerClass   TCCperFTE   FTEs    POSIT ID
2014    One             5000        20      1
2014    Two             1000        30      2
2015    One             15000       40      1
2015    Two             50000       50      2
2016    One             100000      60      1
2016    Two             500000      70      2
```

Any help you guys could give would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the second version of the function `quo` should be `enquo`. What package contains the `currency` function?

Comment: Hi there.  I changed the quo to enquo but am still getting the error:

 Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'symbol'. 

The currency fucntion is contained in the formattable package.

Comment: What if you put the `...` at the end of the argument list?

Comment: Like this?   quantileMaker3 <- function(data,calcCol,...) {

it returns the error  Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: Using `enquo` and either using the argument name of `calcCol` when using the function or putting the `...` last works for me with a simpler example.  Can you add a simple example dataset?  You might also try simplifying the example to the simplest `summarise` that causes the error, possibly just including first summary variable.

Comment: I have added some sample data above. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided sample data, but your function works when modified to use the `mtcars` data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)

quantileMaker3 <- function(data, calcCol, ...) {
  groupCol <- quos(...)
  calcCol <- enquo(calcCol)

  data %>%
    group_by(!!!groupCol) %>%
    summarise('25%' = currency(quantile(!!calcCol, probs = 0.25), digits = 2L),
              '50%' = currency(quantile(!!calcCol, probs = 0.50), digits = 2L),
              '75%' = currency(quantile(!!calcCol, probs = 0.75), digits = 2L),
              avg = currency(mean(!!calcCol), digits = 2L),
              nAgencies = n_distinct(cyl), 
              nFTEs = sum(hp)
    )
}

quantileMaker3(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 7
>     cyl `25%`             `50%`             `75%`             avg               nAgencies nFTEs
>   <dbl> <S3: formattable> <S3: formattable> <S3: formattable> <S3: formattable>     <int> <dbl>
> 1    4. $22.80            $26.00            $30.40            $26.66                    1  909.
> 2    6. $18.65            $19.70            $21.00            $19.74                    1  856.
> 3    8. $14.40            $15.20            $16.25            $15.10                    1 2929.
> ```

With multiple grouping arguments:

```
quantileMaker3(mtcars, mpg, cyl, vs)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 8
> # Groups:   cyl [?]
>     cyl    vs `25%`             `50%`             `75%`             avg               nAgencies nFTEs
>   <dbl> <dbl> <S3: formattable> <S3: formattable> <S3: formattable> <S3: formattable>     <int> <dbl>
> 1    4.    0. $26.00            $26.00            $26.00            $26.00                    1   91.
> 2    4.    1. $22.80            $25.85            $30.40            $26.73                    1  818.
> 3    6.    0. $20.35            $21.00            $21.00            $20.57                    1  395.
> 4    6.    1. $18.03            $18.65            $19.75            $19.12                    1  461.
> 5    8.    0. $14.40            $15.20            $16.25            $15.10                    1 2929.
> ```

Incidentally, you can avoid multiple calls to quantile by using nesting. This won't work if any of the output columns are of class `formattable` (which is what the `currency` function returns), so I've changed the function to create strings for the currency-format columns.

```
quantileMaker3 <- function(data, calcCol, ..., quantiles=c(0.25,0.5,0.75)) {

  groupCol <- quos(...)
  calcCol <- enquo(calcCol)

  data %>%
    group_by(!!!groupCol) %>%
    summarise(values = list(paste0("$", sprintf("%1.2f", quantile(!!calcCol, probs=quantiles)))),
              qnames = list(sprintf("%1.0f%%", quantiles*100)),
              nAgencies = n_distinct(cyl), 
              nFTEs = sum(hp),
              avg = paste0("$", sprintf("%1.2f", mean(!!calcCol)))
    ) %>% 
    unnest %>% 
    spread(qnames, values) 
}

quantileMaker3(mtcars, mpg, cyl, vs)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 8
> # Groups:   cyl [3]
>     cyl    vs nAgencies nFTEs avg    `25%`  `50%`  `75%` 
>   <dbl> <dbl>     <int> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
> 1    4.    0.         1   91. $26.00 $26.00 $26.00 $26.00
> 2    4.    1.         1  818. $26.73 $22.80 $25.85 $30.40
> 3    6.    0.         1  395. $20.57 $20.35 $21.00 $21.00
> 4    6.    1.         1  461. $19.12 $18.03 $18.65 $19.75
> 5    8.    0.         1 2929. $15.10 $14.40 $15.20 $16.25
> ```

Comment: I added sample data above. I think the difference is that i am trying to pass multiple grouping arguments in the call. 

    quantileMaker3(Book2, Year, employerClass, TCCperFTE)

Where Year and employerClass are the grouping arguments and TCCperFTE is for calcCol

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. See update to my answer.

Comment: It worked!!!!  It was just the ordering.  Thank you so much for your help I really, really appreciate it. This is the second time you have helped me on here! You're my hero!!!